Visual studio code
Error: JAVA_HOME not found in your environment. Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the location of your installation" help for visual studio code, this error code keep popping up
I want to run small Java project in VS code and have I installed Java extension pack

This is not a problem with Vs code. Have you installed java?
